# Подскажите пожалуйста как убрать прозрачность у голубого фона

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как убрать прозрачность у голубого фона

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.bgr1
{
    background: rgb(109, 166, 165);
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 18vh;
}
  .bgr2{
   
    background: white;
    width:100%;
    height:182vh;
    
     }

  .btn{
      margin-left:0px;
      margin-top:0px;
      
      
       
      
       width:170px;
       display: inline-block;
       height:100%;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       
     
      font-family:sans-serif;
      font-size:24px;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
      
      text-align:center;
      line-height:12vh;
       margin-left:0px;
       margin-top:0px;
       margin-right:0px;
       margin-bottom:100px;
      vertical-align:middle;
       padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
      transition: 0.2s;

    

  }
   .btn:hover { background: rgb(62, 134, 146);}
  .vhod
  {
        margin-left:0px;
      margin-top:0px;
      
     background:no-repeat;
       
      
      
       display: inline-block;
          
      
       box-sizing: border-box;
       position:absolute;
       width:6px;
      font-family:sans-serif;
      font-size:22px;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
      
      text-align:center;
      
       margin-left:0px;
       margin-top:40px;
       margin-right:0px;
       margin-bottom:100px;
      vertical-align:middle;
       padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
      transition: 0.2s;
      background-image:url(../pictures/login.png);
      
  }
  

 
  

  /*font sans-serif*/
```

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Main</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="bgr1">

            <img src="~/pictures/report.png" alt="альтернативный текст">

                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">Про сервіс</a>
                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">Можливості</a>
                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">ЕЦП</a>
                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">Ціна</a>
                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">Контакти</a>

                <a class="vhod" href="@Url.Action("Registration","Home")"></a>


        </div>

        <div class="bgr2">

            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <style>
                .text {
                    text-align: center;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 35%;
                    font-family: Calibri;
                    font-size: 32px;
                }
            </style>

            <div class="text">
                <p>
                    REPORT<br>
                    звітуйте електронно<br>
                </p>
            </div>
            <img src="~/pictures/hmarka.png" style="position:absolute;left:675px;top:290px;" alt="альтернативный текст">


        </div>
    </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то прозрачный фон - картинка? Возможно, она изначально содержит в себе альфа-канал с прозрачностью, исходя из формата png.

Comment: Не совсем корректный вопрос, так как голубого фона у вас нет. Вы имели ввиду, убрать фон у картинки?

Comment: br3t спасииибо!

Comment: Я тоже искал там голубой, а оказалось - у всех разное цветовосприятие :) Перенес комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема не с прозрачностью голубого фона, а  с его z-index. Поможет установка закрепленной части по z-index выше, чем скролящийся контент:

```
.bgr1 {z-index: 2; }
```